# Appending to files using Expo FileSystem

Tags: react-native, expo

I know it’s possible to fully rewrite a file using the Expo Filesystem API, but is it possible to somehow append a string to a file?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am not a bot. It is a very clear question to me and I am also looking for an answer! Its seems a tough question. More or less the same thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72404754/unable-to-delete-or-append-a-file-in-expo

Comment: Seems after 4 years this is still not possible... See first comment on https://forums.expo.dev/search?q=append

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems not possible with Expo FileSystem. You can only use it for full content rewrites. Alternative package offering appending to files is https://github.com/alpha0010/react-native-file-access